# The real number reached by the probability sequence

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

All numbers are expressed in base $2$.

Start from $0.1_2$

If we reach $r(n) < 1$ after $n$ steps the probability of having $1$ at $n+1^{th}$ decimal position is then $r(n)$.

For example, it is equally probable to have $0.10_2$, $0.11_2$ and then we have two branches, first where it is equally probable to have $0.100_2$ and $0.101_2$ and the other branch where it is more probable to have $0.111_2$.

What is the expected final real value when $n$ tends to infinity? Can you express it in some closed form?

Expressing the problem in the simplest term would be

$$e(1)=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$e(n+1)=e(n)+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}e(n)$$

However, can we apply this recurrence blindly over the expected value? And then if so, can we find some closed form of the recurrence? (I can't find anything shorter than q-Pochhammer.)

The approximation gives $r(\infty) \approx 0.794$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work recursively.  Let $E_n$ denote the expected value of the $n-$ digit entry.  Of course $E_1=\frac 12$.  Let $E$ denote $\lim_{n\to \infty}E_n$, so $E$ is the answer we seek.

We have $$E_n=E_{n-1}\times \left(E_{n-1}+\frac 1{2^n}\right)+(1-E_{n-1})\times \left(E_{n-1}\right)\implies E_n=E_{n-1}\times \left(1+\frac 1{2^n}\right)$$

In the limit we have $$E=\frac 12\times \prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac 1{2^n}\right)$$

That can be evaluated using the [Pochhammer Symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol) and we get $$\boxed {E\approx 0.794744}$$

To justify the recursion, observe that $$E_n=\sum_w p(w)w$$ where $w$ spans the $n-$digit binary decimals and of course $p(w)$ is the probability of observing $w$.  Of course we can write $w=w_{n-1}X$ where $w_{n-1}$ is a word of length $n-1$ and $X$ is $1$ or $0$ with probability $w_{n-1}, 1-w_{n-1}$ respectively. Splitting the sum into two parts, according to whether $X=1,0$ we see that
$$E_n=\sum_{w_{n-1}} p(w_{n-1})w_{n-1} \left(w_{n-1}+ \frac 1{2^n}\right)+\sum_{w_{n-1}} (1-w_{n-1})p(w_{n-1}) w_{n-1}=E_{n-1}\times \left(1+\frac 1{2^n}\right)$$as desired.

Comment: Yes, but the question here as well is to justify calculating the expected value like that.

Comment: What part troubles you?  The recursion itself?  The limit?

Comment: Expressing expected value over expected value. Justifying it. Notice that in this case at step $n$ we make the probability and the expected value the same and move on. It is subtle to justify it.

Comment: Basically I am asking to make the step of mixing the two crystal clear.

Comment: I wrote out the justification for the recursion.  These are all finite sums so there are no convergence issues.

Comment: I think it is close, but I find your indexing weird. $pw$? $p_w$? Still subject to interpretation. I think I am able to clear it up, but if you do not mind for the sake of clarity to do that in the answer.

Comment: Yes, the system does not like iterated subscripts.  I'll relabel....using, say $p(w)$ instead of $p_w$.

Comment: Cool. One tiny thing, the order in two sums should be the same, for example local_probabillity,total_probability,value. You mixed the order making it for a moment difficult to read what is written. This is because that is exactly the subtle point where probability is mixed with the value, so it is, although tiny, actually crucial.

Comment: $$\sum_{w_{n-1}} \left ( w_{n-1}p(w_{n-1}) \right ) \cdot \left(w_{n-1}+ \frac 1{2^n}\right)+\sum_{w_{n-1}} \left ( (1-w_{n-1})   p(w_{n-1}) \right ) \cdot w_{n-1}$$